# Sharing enity among entities in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, annotations, entity

Thank you for reading my question. 
I'm new to Hibernate and I want to use 1 entity in many entities (with Annotaion). I did try to google my problem but still haven't found the answer yet.

Example, I have some entities:

**Address** (ID_Address, Province, District, Ward)

**House**(ID_House, Phone, ID_Address)

**Staff**(ID_Staff, Name, ID_Address)

**Guest**(ID_Guest, Email, ID_Address)

I want one record in Address table only belongs to maybe House or Staff or Guest.

I thinked about One-to-One relationship, but that way my Address entity must declare **private House house** or **private Staff staff** or **private Guest guest** ? Is there any other way to do this, or maybe I missed something?

Comment: *that way my Address entity must declare private House house*: no, that's incorrect. Read the documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you should think of entity relationships as "parent-child". Sometimes the child knows about its parent, and other times it doesn't.

It sounds like in your case, **Address** doesn't need to know about its parent entity, meaning that you don't need to get to the parent from the address entity, you just need to get to Address from a parent entity, like House, Staff, or Guest.

In that case, just declare a `@OneToOne` relationship from parent to Address entity, and not have any reference to the parent from Address. This way, Hibernate will use a column in the parent table that points to the Address table using the address ID.

You may also consider using `@Embeddable` and `@Embedded`. Embeddables are simply "value objects" and they are not considered entities. Embeddables can be stored in the same table as the "parent entity", or they can be stored in their own table.

I hope this helps.